# Randomize the echo char in Highline's ask method?

Tags: ruby, highline

I am trying to randomize the echo character in the Highline gem's `ask` method, but could not get it to work.  Did I not do this right?

```
srand
ask("password:  ") { |q| q.echo = ('a'.ord+rand(26)).chr }
```

The character is randomized for each `ask()` call, but not each character. The first run will echo the same character, i.e. 'cccc'. The next run will echo 'mmmm', etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is a variable value used to determine whether to echo output. [From the highline source](https://github.com/JEG2/highline/blob/master/lib/highline/question.rb#L88):

```
# [echo] Can be set to +true+ or +false+ to control whether or not input will
# be echoed back to the user.  A setting of +true+ will cause echo to
# match input, but any other true value will be treated as a String to
# echo for each character typed.
```

Your code (`('a'.ord+rand(26)).chr`) is being evaluated once per `ask`, stored in the `echo` variable within highline, and then printed out for each character entered.

You can't get it to print a different random character per input character without modifying highline.